# Find another space curve on the cylinder.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Find another space curve on the cylinder:

Given:
$$\frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{z^2}{25} = 1;r(t) = 3\cos(t)i+tj+5\sin(t)k, -2\pi \le t \le 2 \pi$$

What I think:
$$r(t) = -3\cos(t)i+tj+5\sin(t)k$$

Why?
$$\left(\frac{-x}{3}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{z}{5}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{z}{5}\right)^2 = 1 $$

Comment: You should recognize a helix in the given curve. Then any other helix is a solution...

Comment: If there a general method to approaching these types of problems because it clearly isn't intuitive?

Comment: A general method: Play as you want on the second coefficient $y$. The given curve has the shape of an ordinary spring because the second coefficient is $y=t$. Taking $y=t^2$ instead (for example) will give you a spring extended in a faster and a faster way along the $y$ axis. Taking $y=t-cos(t)$ will give you a spring with nodes, etc... Use Geogebra or Desmos to gain an intuitive idea about these curves.